# How do I fix this method for reading structs and putting them in the linked list?

Tags: c, file, struct, linked-list

I need to read a file and place it inside a struct in a double linked list.

But my method doesn't work  `int insert_File(List* pointer_to_pointer)` . Someone can help? How can I fix it? How to read this file and place it correctly in each variable in the struct? Thanks guys.

```
/* ListStudent.h */

struct student
{
    char name[30];
    int cod_student;
    float test_1, test_2, activity, test_optional; /* if test_optional not exist in list_students.txt complete with 0 in struct */
}; 

typedef struct element* List;

int insert_File(List* pointer_to_pointer);
```

```
/* ListStudent.cpp */

struct element
{
    struct element *previous;
    struct student database;
    struct element *next;
};

int insert_File(List* pointer_to_pointer)
{
   if(pointer_to_pointer == NULL)
        return 0;

    element *node = *pointer_to_pointer;

    FILE *pointer_to_file;

    struct student s;

    pointer_to_file = fopen("list_students", "r");

    if(NULL == pointer_to_file)
    {
        cout << "ERROR";
        return 1;
    }

    while(fread(&s, sizeof(struct student), 1, pointer_to_file))
    {
        int a = insert_list_sorted_ascending_by_name(pointer_to_pointer, s);
    }
    fclose(pointer_to_file);
    return 0;
}
```

```
/* ListStudent_main.cpp */

#include "ListStudent.cpp"

int main(){

List *pointer_to_pointer;

pointer_to_pointer = create_list();

int f = insert_File(pointer_to_pointer);

return 0;
}
```

File txt

```
Marcos David 885487 9.4 5.4 8.5 0
Victor Corleone 445587 9.8 5.7 9.5 9
Alban Sernen 115400 8.4 8.4 5.5
Alban Aline 775487 1.4 2.4 1.5 1.1
Alban Victor 905487 2.4 2.6 4.5 1.5
```

Comment: It looks to me that there are lots of problems here, but there's also a lot of missing code so it's hard to be sure.

But the obvious problem is that `fread` is for binary data but your input is text.

Comment: changed tag from C++ to C, since there's no C++ here.

Comment: Also it's wrong to include one cpp file in another. Instead you should compile both cpp files separately and link them together.

Comment: Can you describe the issue in more detail than "doesn't work"?

Comment: @john `fread` is not necessarily for binary data. You can read text data in chunks, processing these before reading next junk. What indeed is wrong is trying to read textual data into binary structs without any appropriate conversion...

Answer (score 0):

Data representation in file is not the same as in memory.

While, for instance, the `int` value in memory consists of an exact, fix number of bytes (typically four on modern hardware), numbers in text consist of a variable series of bytes. Additionally, the values of the bytes are not the same.

`885487` in a text file consists of the bytes `0x38 0x38 0x35 0x34 0x38 0x37`, whereas the same number in memory (32-bit int provided) looks like `0xEF 0x82 0x0D 0x00` (little endian representation!).

Sizes of other members do not match either, additionally, there will be no space character (0x20) in between the binary data members.

For illustration: Data inside `s` after first call to 
`fread(&s, sizeof(struct student), 1, pointer_to_file)`:

```
name          == "Marcos David 885487 9.4 5.4 8." // you read EXACTLY 30 chars
cod_student   == 170 926 133 // "5 0\n" interpreted as 32-bit int (little endian)
test_1        == <some value> // "Vict" interpreted as 32-bit float
test_2        == <some value> // "or C" interpreted as 32-bit float
activity      == <some value> // "orle" interpreted as 32-bit float
test_optional == <some value> // "one " interpreted as 32-bit float
```

I didn't make the effort to convert the characters to actual floating point values, suppose it's pretty obvious that the values won't be those you actually wanted to have... I assumed unix line endings – if you use windows ones, then there will be an additional `\r` character in  front of the `\n`, shifting the characters used for filling the floats by 1, but that won't change anything in reading unwanted data.

You now have two options:

- Either you store the students already as binary (while writing, open file with `"wb"` option, for reading use `"rb"`, to make sure that there won't be special handling for line breaks). Be aware that the file won't be human readable any more then!
- Or you need to convert the textual data into binary one.

For the latter option I personally would read the file line by line (C: [fgets](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets); C++: [std::getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)) and parse these lines on their own.

You are in the unlucky situation that you have chosen a separator character for the data items that can occur in one of the data fields as well: the space character. If you change the field separator to something different (e. g. `|` – there are special separator characters as well, ASCII 0x1C – 0x1F, ideal for our purpose on reading, but hard to enter in a text editor...), then you will make your life much easier: Just tokenise the string with this separator character and convert the substrings.

For now, you'd look up in the string the first digit (assuming that digits won't occur in a name) and copy the characters in front of (apart from the last space) into the name field. Don't forget to null-terminate the string.

From now on, you can just tokenise, beginning at the digit just found before. In C, have a look at [strtok](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) function for tokenising and at [strtol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) and [strtof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtof) for conversion.

In C++ (as you tagged that initially), there are quite a number of different ways how you can process the remaining string (maybe simplest using a `std::istringstream`).